# How to import a file for karma - javascript unit testing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am using Karma to unit test some of my scripts that are part of my rails application, but I am having trouble importing a file 'utility.js' that has several utility functions which I use throughout my code.  It works fine in when I run the rails app, my manifest loads the file first and the functions are globally available, but when I use this code at the top of my karma test file, the function `make_index_array()` which is defined in utility.js is not found.  make_index_array() is called by one of the methods in the class I under test (DetailBudget).

```
import  "../../app/assets/javascripts/utility.js"
import {DetailBudget} from "../../app/assets/javascripts/budgeting_scripts/detail_budget_classes.js"
```

Here is the error message:

```
START:
Chrome 71.0.3578 (Mac OS X 10.14.2) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught ReferenceError: make_index_array is not defined",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught ReferenceError: make_index_array is not defined"
  }
  Confirm test setup
    ✔  does works

Finished in 0.002 secs / 0.002 secs @ 10:57:35 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Here is the make_index_array function as defined in utility.js:

```
function make_index_array(low, high) {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        list.push(i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Karma is set to use ChromeBrowser, running Rails 5.2 (There are two tests in this suite, the first one (the one that passes) is just there to make sure the setup works.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to import some external js file in unit tests, then you should configure it in `karma.conf.js` as well.

### Example:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
  ...
  files: [
    "<Utility.js file location from this config file location>"
  ],
  ...
  });
};
```

If path of your `utility.js` from `karma.conf.js` is `../../app/assets/javascripts/utility.js`, then your configuration in `karma.conf.js` will be:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
  ...
  files: [
    "../../app/assets/javascripts/utility.js"
  ],
  ...
  });
};
```

For more details of `files` configuration, refer: https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html